# prove the continuity of the function

Tags: general-topology

Let $C_{n}$ be the subspace of $R^{2}$ defined by $C_{n}=\left\{(x,y)|\left(x-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{2}+y^{2}=\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{2}\right\}$.Let Y be the subspace $$Y=\cup_\left\{n\in z^{+}\right\}C_{n}$$ of $R^{2}$,let $X$ be the subspace  $C_{1}\times Z_{+}$ of $R^{2}\times R$. Define $g:X\rightarrow Y$ by $g(((x,y),n))=(\dfrac{x}{n},\dfrac{y}{n})$,prove that g is continuous and surjective but not quotient.

Ironically,I can prove that this map is surjective and not quotient but couldn't find a proper way to explain it is continuous.Could anyone provide me the strict mathematical proof of continuity? Appreciate in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $\mathbf x = (x,y)$

You need a distance metric. 
$d(\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2) = (x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2$ is the square of the euclidean metric, and will suffice.

Definition of continuity:

$\forall \epsilon >0, \forall \mathbf x,\mathbf x_2 \in X, \exists \delta : d(\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2)<\delta \implies d(g(\mathbf x_1),g(\mathbf x_2))<\epsilon$

$d(g(\mathbf x_1),g(\mathbf x_2)) = \frac 1{n^2}d(\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2)$

$\delta = n^2\epsilon$

Comment: couple with the fact that all metrics are equivalent in finite-dimensional space. So it doesn't matter which metric you use to show continuity.